Excel formula to calculate elapsed hours between timestamps
I am looking to calculate the elapsed hours between timestamps only using the timestamps for status codes "COMPLETE" & "ASSGN" for each trailer in sequential order. The "COMPLETE" & "ASSGN" timestamps should have a different trip ID in the calculation. Sample of the data is attached in the image. I have done this manually using a basic formula which is included in the image but I would like to automate this if possible. This is to calculate trailer dwell time between trips. The issue Im having is there will be multiple timestamps for each status code and they should calculate in sequential order.
Sample Data

What have you tried yourself? Cell A minus cell B? DATEDIF?

Im using (Cell A - Cell B)*24 as the manual formula but Id like to have the entire process done by formula if possible.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78663289/4961700

Can you explain the logic for taking the green Assign-line and not the one underneath?

Ideally the formula would select the first instance of the "ASSGN" timestamp after the "COMPLETE" timestamp, the system we use sometimes records a duplicate timestamp but usually they have the same date/time.

Then explain the next assign line being a different time where prior complete would be the green. To me this does not seem logic to your description

Sample data
Solution:
Formulas should be inserted into E2 cell and F2 cell and then copied down in E and F columns respectivelly.
Obviously, just one of E or F columns would be needed, based on your preference of displaying the duration.
To calculate dwell time for each trailer between COMPLETE and the next ASSGN timestamp sequentially, I used the following formulas:
Column E (Duration in [h]:mm format):
=IF(D2="ASSGN";C2-MAX(FILTER(C$2:C2;(D$2:D2="COMPLETE")*(B$2:B2=B2);C2));"")

This formula calculates the time difference between the current ASSGN timestamp and the latest COMPLETE timestamp for the same trailer.
FILTER retrieves only relevant timestamps where Status Code = COMPLETE and the trailer matches.
MAX() ensures the most recent COMPLETE timestamp is used.
Column F (Duration in Decimal Hours):
=IF(D2="ASSGN";(C2-MAX(FILTER(C$2:C2;(D$2:D2="COMPLETE")*(B$2:B2=B2);C2)))*24;"")

This formula extends the previous one by multiplying the result by 24 to convert the time difference into decimal hours.
Explanation:
IF(D2="ASSGN", ...) ensures calculations are performed only for rows where ASSGN appears.
FILTER dynamically filters timestamps for the same trailer with the COMPLETE status.
MAX ensures the latest COMPLETE timestamp is used sequentially.
Column E provides the result in [h]:mm, while Column F converts it to hours with two decimal places.
Result: The solution dynamically calculates trailer dwell times, ensuring sequential order and matching trailer IDs.
Formulas in your case:
G2 cell:
=IF(G2="ASSGN";F2-MAX(FILTER(F$2:F2;(G$2:G2="COMPLETE")*(D$2:D2=D2);F2));"")

When copied down, in G5 cell:
=IF(G5="ASSGN";F5-MAX(FILTER(F$2:F5;(G$2:G5="COMPLETE")*(D$2:D5=D5);F5));"")


As I made a simplified version of your dataset (see Sample data picture in my answer), I have different columns.
In your case @Kristen, the formula in the J column should be:
in J2 cell:
code=IF(G2="ASSGN";F2-MAX(FILTER(F$2:F2;(G$2:G2="COMPLETE")(D$2:D2=D2);F2));"")code
when you copy it down, for example, to row 5...
in J5 cell:
code=IF(G5="ASSGN";F5-MAX(FILTER(F$2:F5;(G$2:G5="COMPLETE")(D$2:D5=D5);F5));"")code
